# Runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property using set

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple script that declares a few variables as a range but I am getting the error

> Run-time error '438':
>
> Object doesn't support this property or method

What am I missing?

```
Sub copyId()

Dim numberID As Range, column As Range, pasteId As Range

Set column = Workbooks("Book4.xlsm").Worksheets(1).Columns("C")
Set pasteId = Workbooks("Book5.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("A").xlUp

For Each numberID In column
    If numberID Like "########" Or numberID Like "#########" Then numberID.Copy Destination:=pasteId
Next numberID

End Sub
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlUp` is used with [`Range.End`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end). Then, you need to determine the last cell *inside* the loop:

```
For Each numberID In column
    If numberID Like "########" Or numberID Like "#########" Then 
        With Workbooks("Book5.xlsx").Worksheets(1)
            numberID.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    End If
Next
```

**EDIT**:

You (presumably) don't want to loop through every single cell in the column... find the last row instead:

```
Dim sourceBook As Workbook
Set sourceBook = Workbooks("Book4.xlsm")

Dim destBook As Workbook
Set destBook = Workbooks("Book5.xlsx")

Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = sourceBook.Worksheets(1)

Dim destSheet As Worksheet
Set destSheet = destBook.Worksheets(1)

With sourceSheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
End With

Dim sourceCells As Range
Set sourceCells = sourceSheet.Range("C1:C" & lastRow)

For Each numberID in sourceCells
    If numberID Like "########" Or numberID Like "#########" Then 
        With destSheet
            numberID.Copy Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Side note: the `With` block is binding to a compile-time `Object`, which means the 
`.Cells` and `.Rows.Count` member calls qualified with it are still implicitly late-bound, thus somewhat error-prone.

Answer (score 3):

[BigBen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66035277/1188513) already identified the correct incantation, but the *cause* of this particular error (run-time error number 438) is typically the use of *implicit late binding*, which is bad because it defers to run-time errors that could otherwise be caught much earlier, at compile-time.

Everything after `Worksheets(1)` is implicitly late-bound:

> ```
> Set pasteId = Workbooks("Book5.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Columns("A").xlUp
> ```

That means the `.Columns("A")` call is resolved at run-time, and the `.xlUp` member call on the returned object is completely invisible to the compiler, which is what's deferring the problem to run-time.

Whenever you type a dot operator (`.`) and the editor isn't giving you a list of available members, you are invoking a member without the compiler's safety net, and even `Option Explicit` cannot save you: the compiler is happy with "so that's a variant, we'll figure out its member calls at run-time", but that doesn't mean you should be happy with it all the same.

By introducing object variables, you can give the compiler the nudge it's missing:

```
Dim book As Workbook
Set book = Application.Workbooks("Book5.xlsx") 'did the macro open this book? if so, you should already have a reference to it.

Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set sheet = book.Worksheets(1)
```

Reason being, the `Sheets.Item` property is returning an `Object`, and that is exactly what you're invoking with `Worksheets(1)`: the `Workbook.Worksheets` property returns a `Sheets` object, but `Sheets.Item` (its default property) is returning `Object`, which means the resolution of any chained member call is deferred to run-time.

With a local `Worksheet`-typed variable, the compiler is no longer only seeing `Object`; it knows what the members of a `Worksheet` are, so the `Columns` property can resolve at compile-time now. Similarly, `Range.Columns` yields a `Range` object, but here we're implicitly invoking its hidden `[_Default]` property (giving it `"A"` as an argument), and that returns a `Variant` whose resolution is also deferred to run-time, so we introduce another variable:

```
Dim columnA As Range
Set columnA = sheet.Columns("A")
```

And now this becomes a *compile-time* error, because `xlUp` isn't going to be listed when you type that `.` dot:

```
Set pasteId = ColumnA.xlUp
```

[image: compile error: method or data member not found]

And that is the compile-time equivalent of run-time error 438.